# Is there any way to copy locked data from a protected sheet onto my clipboard in Excel?

Tags: excel-2007

I would like to copy locked data from a protected sheet.  Is there any way to keep the sheet protected, but copy the information to the clipboard?  Should I use an export function instead of the copy function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can copy locked cells from a protected worksheet without any problem, unless "Select Locked Cells" is unchecked in the Protection dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to do that programmatically, you can unprotect, copy or whatever you want to do, protect again.

Comment: It seems to lose the copied information on the clipboard after the information is protected again.

Comment: There is no reason it would do so. Any case, finish the copying or whatever you want to do before protecting back again. The other way to do this is to loop through the range to be copied and do something like that: TargetRange.Cells(i, j).Value = SourceRange.Cells(i, j).Value